# python script that generates a custom wordlist

Tags: python, text, generator, word-list

I'm trying to write a script that generates a custom wordlist.

Instructions

> - It has to be between 8-15 characters
> - Alphanumeric characters
> - Will contain a combination of the three full key words: NOSAM, ESYC, UMG
> - Any other characters prepended/appended to the key words will be numerical
> - Always has these numbers:
>
> 20 21 22 23 24
>
> - This includes uppercase and lower-case permutations: (ex: esYc, NOSam, Umg)
> - Randomize the capitalization of words
> - The numbers go in between, before, and after the key words as well
>
> Examples:
>
> - Nosam20umG23
> - 2220ESYcumG
> - ESyc24Nosam20
> - EsycNOSAMUMG
> - noSAM21UMg

```py
from random import choice
from itertools import product
import string
min_len = int(input('Enter minimum length of password: '))
max_len = int(input('Enter maximum length of password: '))
counter = 0
key_word = ['NOSAM', 'ESYC', 'UMG'] + ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
key_word = ''.join(choice((str.upper, str.lower))(i) for i in key_word)

charater = key_word
file_open = open("wordlist.txt", 'w')
for i in range(min_len,max_len+1):
    for j in product(charater, repeat = i):
        word = "".join(j)
        file_open.write(word)
        file_open.write('\n')
        counter += 1
    print("Wordlist of {} passwords created".format(counter))
```

Comment: whats the problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: It changes the key word ['NOSAM', 'ESYC', 'UMG'] to something completely different when it generates the text file. I want only different combination of the 
 key word ['NOSAM', 'ESYC', 'UMG']   in lowercase and upper case and it randomize lower case and upper case. It also separate the numbers. Whereas I just want these number to go in between, after or before exact each key words instead of between the character of each key words.